# Update Component after user logged in (React / Redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux

Yesterday I implemented an authentication system inside my react app. Additional I added Redux.

So now I have following reducers:

- appReducer
- listReducer

My store looks something like this:

```
{
  appReducer: {
    user: {
      guid: null
    }
  }
  listReducer: {
    list: []
  }
}
```

Component Structure:

```
- App (logic for authentication)
-- Navigation
-- Routes
--- ListPage (logic for list)
```

I want that the `list[]` rendered inside my ListPage component gets refreshed when a user logs in (when guid changes in store).
The current solution is, that i do a fetchList inside my AppActions, but I'm sure, that thats not a nice way to get what I want.

How do I correctly trigger my `fetchList` action, when guid's value changes?

Thanks!

Edit: fetchList is a redux action, which includes an axios api call

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Redux you are updating the value of `guid` by dispatching an action to the reducer. I would say you should dispatch a list update action right after you updated the `guid`. As the `list` values get mapped as props in the component, it will get re-rendered.

Comment: yeah, right! that's exactly what I was doing, but I wondered if it is somehow possible to let fetchList run by itself after the guid changes to another value than null - my problem is not that my component wont re-render after i dispatch an action - i just dont want to dispach another action :)

Comment: I see :) In this case you should create a listener for your redux store which will be responsible to dispatch the update if the `guid` changed. You can achieve it with the `subscribe()` function on your store. More info: https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribe-listener

Answer (score 1):

I would make fetchList call inside componentDidMount function on your ListPage but also making an if statement, somethin like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
    if(this.props.store.guid !== "null"){
        this.props.fetchList();
    }
}
```

I hope you get the point.
BTW in your store I don't know if you made it on purpose but I'd use null without quotation marks.

Comment: Hey, no I didn't - just corrected the typo. So this approach is what I have already tried, but I did it by adding a function in my reducer, which returns user's guid from store. (I map this to my props in mapStateToProps `guid: getGuid(state)`) The problem is, that when i try `if(this.props.guid !== null)`, no fetchList gets triggered after my user loggs in? AFAIK componentDidMount doesn't get called after a props change, am I right?

Comment: Yes I think use the lifecycle is not a good idea for this case, but if you have that functions that returns if user i logged why don't you just use it directly in your render something like: {this.props.guid !== null ? <ul><li>List</li></ul> : null }

Comment: hey, yeah it would work on the client side perfectly, but i have to call fetchList, because I have to call an API in order to get my data. So i have to call fetchReports everytime the user logs in / out. Thats my problem...